# Reliable / Popular data visualization toolkit for the web

Tags: graphics, visualization, analytics

I'm looking for a reliable toolkit in any web-neutral[A] language, actively maintained / developed, stable that allows me to build graphs, charts, display data dynamically, allow drag-n-drop of datasets and refreshes automatically.

[Carlos Scheidegger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/221007/carlos-scheidegger) recommended - http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ which looks great! But I'm looking to see what others are there and what ppl are using...

[A] What I mean is something like js / jquery, etc. which can be generated by any web language like php, python, perl, etc

Answer (score 1):

Check out the MIT Smile project, RGraph, and of course [Processing](http://www.processing.org/) (if you are willing to deal with applets).

Answer (score 1):

[Raphael](http://raphaeljs.com/) is also a good option.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out Google Analytics, Yahoo Web Analytics, Omniture SiteCatalyst, or Webtrends.

Comment: Hi... no my question isnt for website analytics, but other general data analysis/visualizations...